# Object has no attribute 'update' (Python)

Tags: python

so i just started on my first ever project, (making a 'snake'-game).
But one of my lines (`Line 65, in run_game, snakehead.update()'`), has an error called `'snakehead' object has no attribute 'update'` and i tried some thing but i couldnt get it to work...

for the full code:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *


class SnakeHead(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.image = pygame.image.load('data/snake_head.png') 
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = 320
        self.rect.centery = 240    

        self.direction = (0,-1) 
        self.crashed = False


    def render(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)

        def update(self):
            self.rect.centerx += self.direction(0) * 2
            self.rect.centery += self.direction(1) * 2

            if self.rect.left < 0:
                self.rect.left = 0
                self.crashed = True

            if self.rect.right > 639:
                self.rect.right = 639
                self.crashed = True

            if self.rect.top < 0:
                self.rect.top = 0
                self.crashed = True

            if self.rect.bottom > 479:
                self.rect.bottom = 479
                self.crashed = True 

def run_game():
    pygame.init()

    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640,480)) 

    snakehead = SnakeHead()

    clock = pygame.time.Clock() 




    while 1:

        clock.tick(32)

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                return 


        screen.fill((175,175,175))

        snakehead.update() 
        snakehead.render(screen) 

        pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: Your indentation appears wrong. `update` is a function local to the `render` method, not a method of the `Snakehead` class.

Comment: What's with the downvote of this question with no explanation?  He included all of the requisites and it's a valid question, common among those learning Python and Python classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would work if you made a slight change to the indentation of your update method:

```
class SnakeHead(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.image = pygame.image.load('data/snake_head.png') 
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = 320
        self.rect.centery = 240    

        self.direction = (0,-1) 
        self.crashed = False


    def render(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)


    def update(self):
        self.rect.centerx += self.direction(0) * 2
        self.rect.centery += self.direction(1) * 2

        if self.rect.left < 0:
            self.rect.left = 0
            self.crashed = True

        if self.rect.right > 639:
            self.rect.right = 639
            self.crashed = True

        if self.rect.top < 0:
            self.rect.top = 0
            self.crashed = True

        if self.rect.bottom > 479:
            self.rect.bottom = 479
            self.crashed = True
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks! im sorry for being pretty stupid and forgetting about that indentation :D

Comment: We've all made much stupider mistakes, and we'll all make more.

Answer (score 1):

Check your indentation. update is defined as a sub-function of render.

Comment: Omg, thanks to you, my sir. I didnt realize i had it as a sub-function.